# Is there any way to convert a date string with short monthname to datetime/date?

Tags: sql-server, date, type-conversion

I have to convert dates in the form '2017-Oct-23' to the date or datetime format in sql server. How can I do that? Is there a builtin function or do i need to use case in combination with convert?

Comment: CAST('2017-Oct-23' as datetime)

Answer (score 1):

```
-- To convert it to date
SELECT CAST('2017-Oct-23' AS DATE) AS [Date]

-- To convert it to datetime
SELECT CAST('2017-Oct-23' AS DATETIME) AS [Datetime]
```

Output

```
Date
2017-10-23

Datetime
2017-10-23 00:00:00.000
```

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a builtin function?

Yes, you can see **[CAST and CONVERT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql)** which include `Date and Time Styles`.

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATE, '2017-Oct-23') First, 
       CAST('2017-Oct-23' AS DATE) Second
```